# jquery get indexes of all items in a list from a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box like:

```
<select name="blah" id="meh">
<option value="1">Car</option>
<option value="2">Horse</option>
<option value="3">Van</option>
</select>
```

I then have some Json like:

```
[Object { id="1",  label="Car",  value="1"}, Object { id="3",  label="Van",  value="3"}]
```

What I want to do is get the indexes from the select that match the values in my json and also i want to get the indexes from my select that are not in my json.  So i've written this bit of code:

```
$.map( data, function( item ) {
        $('#meh option').filter(function() {
            if($(this).text() == item.label){
                $('ul.chzn-results').append('<li id="meh_chzn_o_'+$(this).index()+'" class="active-result">' + item.label + '</li>');
                }
        });
});
```

Now this get's me the indexes that are in my json; however, i'm struggling with getting those that are not in the json and then doing a `$('#meh_chzn_c_'+$(this).index()+').remove();` on those that are not part of the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i came up with the following code to fix this issue:

```
$.getJSON(surl+'contacts/_ajax/ajax_listTribes.cfm?bIsAjax=true&lstTribeIDs='+lsttribeids, function(data) {
    var arrids = $.map(data,function(obj){ return obj.id });
    $('#lstTribeIDs option').each(function(){
        if( $.inArray($(this).val() , arrids) != -1 ) {
            //do stuff
        } else {
            //do other stuff
        }
    });
});
```

So taking the JSON objects, getting the 'id' part of them and coverting to an array, then looping over my `<select>` and checking whether the value of the current `<option>` is within my array.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like your json is messed up..

```
{ id="1",  label="Car",  value="1"}
```

All the key value pairs are supposed to be in **"" Double Quotes** .
And the key value pairs separated by a **colon :**

So your json should look like this

```
[
  { "id" : "1",  "label" : "Car",  "value" :"1"},
  { "id" : "3",  "label" : "Van" ,  "value" : "3"}
]
```

After json object was fixed this was the output.

[Check DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/u6dpt/2/)

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question at all.

Comment: yes, but i'm trying to get a list of indexes of all items in a select that exist in json, and a list of all indexes of items in a select that do not exist in json.